# Looking for title of a sci-fi book about dystopian future with implantable devices

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been looking for this book on and off for a pretty long time now. Description for the novel:

- About +-10 years old, I think
- Green and black cover, I think written in matrix/dot font
- Hardcover, might come in paperback
- I thought the title was something like 'Click', but I'm not sure if I can't find the book under this title because of how generic the name is or because it's a different title
- It's a story mainly about implantable devices (which I thought was also the name of the title was the name of the device, could be wrong). The devices allow people to access the internet with just their mind. I think at the beginning of the book the main character is driving or talking about driving and communicating with some woman or woman-like AI. He mentions how normally everyone can just check their devices for directions but he is what's call 'a wild', someone without the device. I definitely remember that people without the device were called 'wilds'.
- The main character's father or grandfather owns a newspaper business that operates out of Mexico, but the details of this subplot don't really get revealed until later in the book.
- The newspaper is supposed to be some resistance rebel newspaper of some kind (probably that a lot of wilds read) but turns out the main character's dad/grandpa works with the government because it was more profitable or something
- I think the start of the book mentions something about the AI can take the form and voice of anyone the device wearer wants
- Male author
- About 200-400 pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could this be "[The Boost](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1732459)" by Stephen Baker? Published in 2014 it is more or less compatible with the poster's estimate of publication ten years ago.

It deals with a future where almost everybody has implantable devices. The problem is that the devices are manufactured by China, and include a "backdoor" which lets the Chinese government monitor the wearers' activities. People who have the devices removed are indeed called "wilds", who form a resistance network. Some reviews are available at [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18490545-the-boost). In addition, the cover is indeed mainly green and black.

[image: Cover of "The Boost" by Stephen Baker]

Comment: Yes! Thanks a bunch.